# Loop over strings in r

Tags: r, loops

I'd like to know what is wrong with my code rather than a solution. I wish to loop over some strings my data is as follows:

```
id    source    transaction

 1     a > b       6 > 0
 2     J > k       5
 3     b > c       4 > 0
```

I have a list and wish to go over this list and find the rows that contains that element and compute average.

```
mylist <- c ("a", "b")
```

So my desired output will for one of the element in the list  is

```
source  avg
a        6 
b        2
```

I do not know who to loop over the list and send them to a csv file. I tried this

```
mylist <- c( "a", "b" )

for(i in mylist)
{

  KeepData <- df [grepl(i, df$source), ]
   KeepData <- cSplit(KeepData, "transaction", ">", "long")

  avg<- mean(KeepData$transactions)
  result <- list(i,avg )

  write.table(result ,file="C:/Users.csv", append=TRUE,sep=",",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)

}
```

But It gives me "NA" result with the following warning

> Warning messages: 1: In mean.default(KeepData$transactions) :
>   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA 2: In
>   mean.default(KeepData$transactions) :   argument is not numeric or
>   logical: returning NA

Comment: Are you sure the expected mean value is correct for the new data

Comment: One problem with the `for` loop is check the output of `cSplit` and the one above it ie. grepl.  use `print` for each step and you will understand the reason, here the `transaction` column gets replicated after the `cSplit`, also it is not `transactions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` to split the 'source' and convert the dataset to 'long' format, then specify the 'i', grouped by 'source', get the `mean` of 'transaction' (using `data.table` methods)

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, "source", " > ", "long")[source %in% mylist, .(avg = mean(transaction)), source]
#   source avg
#1:      a   6
#2:      b   5
```

---

Or another option is `separate_rows` from `tidyr` to convert to 'long' format, then use the `dplyr` methods to `summarise` after grouping by 'source'

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
separate_rows(df1, source) %>%
        filter(source %in% mylist) %>%
        group_by(source) %>% 
        summarise(avg  = mean(transaction))
```

#### Update

For the new dataset ('df2'), we need to split both the columns to 'long' format, and then get the `mean` of 'transaction' grouped by 'source'

```
cSplit(df2, 2:3,  " > ", "long")[source %in% my_list, .(avg = mean(transaction)), source]
#   source avg
#1:      a   6
#2:      b   2
```

---

The `for` loop can be modified to

```
for(i in mylist) {
   KeepData <-  cSplit(df2, 2:3,  ">", "long")
   KeepData <- KeepData[grepl(i, source)]
   avg<- mean(KeepData$transaction)
   result <- list(i,avg )
   print(result)
   write.table(result ,file="C:/Users.csv", 
             append=TRUE,sep=",",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
 }
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] 6

#[[1]]
#[1] "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] 2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, source = c("a > b", "J > k", "b > c"
 ), transaction = c(6L, 5L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", "source", "transaction"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


df2 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, source = c("a > b", "J > k", "b > c"
), transaction = c("6 > 0", "5", "4 > 0")), .Names = c("id", 
"source", "transaction"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun it works for this example but I main wish to know what is wrong  with this code to apply in my situation,  in my work the transaction column is also like 2 > 3 . How do I apply to that

Comment: @MFR Are you saying that the transaction column is `character` class?  It is not clear from the comments

Comment: Thanks @akrun does `source !%in% my_list` compute the average of sources which are not include sources in my list?

Comment: @MFR You have to use `!source %in% my_list`